# Does Binomial and Poisson distributions have to start from 0 instead of a positive integer as the value of first bin?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

Is the above claim true? If so, why? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the definition of those distributions. But you could define a new random variable that is equal to a binomial or poisson random variable plus some constant that you like. In that case, the smallest value that new random variable could take on would be nonzero.